# Giving Coinspot Secret API to developer?

Tags: cryptography, secret-key

I assume it's a bad idea to give away your Secret API Key. I have a freelancer making a script that accesses Coinspot's API, and he has asked for it.

I'd appreciate anyone's advice on the topic.

Comment: If you give it away, it's not much of a secret, is it? *I met this stranger on a web site, and I'm going to pay them to do some work for me. They've asked me to give them my username and a list of my secret questions with their answers for my bank account's password reset page. Is that a good idea?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming.  Perhaps try security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciate it. Feel free to move it to security.